# Can you insert a formula into the tab of a worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am creating a worksheet that will gather all of its displayed information from a database produced Excel file.  This data will include a property name that I want to display on the tab.

Is it possible to use a formula to dynamically change the label of a tab?

Comment: No, this cannot be done with a formula only. This can be done using VBA however. Are you open to using VBA in your workbook?

Comment: I'm not currently using VBA in the notebook.  I do know some Visual Basic.  But I'm not familiar as to how to incorporate VBA into a spreadsheet.

If you have some website suggestion on how to do this, I'm all ears!!  And thanks for any ideas you have.

Answer (score 3):

Open Excel, open your workbook, hit Alt-F11, start coding your VBA. :)

I'd suggest editing the Worksheet's 'Change' method and assign a name to 'ActiveSheet.Name'.

ie: `ActiveSheet.Name = "YourName"`

That way any time the sheet is changed, the name (which is what shows on the tab) will update to "Your name".

If you want to make it more dynamic, then instead of a static string you can assign the name from the value of a cell as such:

`ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value`

[image]

This will hopefully get you going towards where you need to be for your specific case. :)

Comment: Awesome!  And that was too easy!!!

Thanks for the help.  That will make a HUGE difference!

Don

Comment: @DonWilson No problem, glad it helped.